# Is there an activity log for Facebook group administrators?

Tags: facebook-groups

I'm the creator of a public Facebook group of my university. I added another administrator to help me to control the posts. Some time ago a member said that a post of his was deleted from the group. I didn't delete anything but maybe the other admin did, or the member deleted his own post. Now many people accuse me of deleting that post.

Is there any way to uncover who deleted the post?

Or is there any way to evidence that the other admin and I did not delete the post?

Comment: Have you ever found out an answer to this? I noticed there's an Admin activity log for some groups and not others. In one of my groups, I can see the Admin activity log, but another group where an admin is accused of deleting posts, the option is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tap 'more' (this has 3 dots above it) & then tap 'View Group info' & then tap 'Admin activity', a list of all activity including deletions & approvals should show up.